# Toggle table row visibility based on presence of td class

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I toggle multiple rows in a table if the `<td>` class is set to an specific class. For instance toggle all rows if they contain the `class="foo"`.

```
<table id="bar">
  <tr>
    <td>hello</td>
    <td class="foo">there</td>
    <td class="foo">bye</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "toggle"? Change the visibility of the entire row, to either show or hide them all at the same time?

Comment: @Phrogz: yes, show/hide.

Comment: Forgot to mention, no framework, pure JS

Comment: I echo the suggestion by @Hogsmill: you should consider using jQuery. More than half the JS in my suggestion is just to implement a not-as-flexible-as-jQuery selector function. (Although  it could be shorter if you know your browser base will have `querySelectorAll`.) If you use [CDN hosted jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery#CDN_Hosted_jQuery) your customers may even have it in their caches already, so it's 'free'.

Comment: 100% agree that you should be using a framework for this sort of thing, otherwise it's all too easy to stumble over browser incompatibilities.

Comment: @delimiter01 Since you appear to be new to Stack Overflow, know that you should "vote up" any answers or comments that you found useful, and "accept" (big checkmark) the answer that solved your problem (if any).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a non-jQuery solution, written just for you: http://phrogz.net/tmp/toggling_rows_with_class.html

Here's the relevant JS:

```
window.onload = function() {
  var visible = true;
  document.getElementById('toggle').onclick = function() {
    visible = !visible;
    var tds = findElementsWithClass('td', 'foo');
    for (var i=0, len=tds.length; i<len; ++i) {
      tds[i].parentNode.style.display = visible ? '' : 'none';
    }
  };
}


function findElementsWithClass(tagName, className) {
  if (document.querySelectorAll) {
    return document.querySelectorAll(tagName + "." + className);
  } else {
    var results = [];
    var all = document.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
    var regex = new Regexp("(?:^|\\s)" + tagName + "(?:\\s|$)");
    for (var i=0, len=all.length; i<len; ++i) {
      if (regex.test(all[i].className)) {
        results.push(all[i]);
      }
    }
    return results;
  }
}
```

Comment: You should post the code from your solution instead of just linking to it. It ensures that interested viewers 5 years from now will be able to see it.

Comment: No, the js is fine. Looks like your update came 1 second before my comment, so indeed you beat me to the punch. ;o)

Answer (score 2):

#### Modify the class

Why is everyone using selectors? There is already a class attached to all the appropriate elements, so why not just modify the class?

This function will find the class of a given name, and set an attribute for that class. Be careful if you have multiple classes with coincident names in different stylesheets, because the function isn't!

```
function changeStyle(stylename,attribute,newvalue) {
  var cssRules = 'rules';
  if(document.styleSheets[0].cssRules) {
    cssRules = 'cssRules';
  }
  for(var sheetId=0; sheetId<document.styleSheets.length; sheetId++) {
    var sheet = document.styleSheets[sheetId];
    for(var ruleId=0; ruleId<sheet[cssRules].length; ruleId++) {
      var rule = sheet[cssRules][ruleId];
      if(rule.selectorText == "."+stylename) {
         rule.style.setProperty(attribute,newvalue,"");
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Now, just call

```
changeStyle('foo','display','none');
```

and the cells should disappear, then with `'block'` to get them back (IE can't do the more recent display styles like ). I suspect that in a table you'll want to hide entire rows rather than just cells, but you can also make them disappear by setting `visibility` to `hidden` - they will still take up space, but not draw.

See, no jquery, no homemade element selectors. Just a slightly annoying bit of javascript to loop through the stylesheets and their rules...

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$("table td.specific_class").toggle();
```

## Edit

```
/* Go through the table rows */
var trs = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
for (var i = 0; i < trs.length; i++ ) {
    var myClass, tds, line_done = false;
    /* Go through the table cells */
    tds = trs[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
    for ( var k = 0; k < tds.length; k++ ){
        /* Check each class of each cell */
        myClasses = tds[k].className.split(' ');
        for ( var j = 0; j < myClasses.length; j++ ){
            /* If the class corresponds we toggle the row and break until the next row */
            if ( myClasses[j].className == "foo" ){
                trs[i].style.display = trs[i].style.display == "none" ? "block" : "none";
                line_done = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if ( line_done ){
          break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The question wasn't tagged with jQuery.

Comment: True, but it shows how much simpler the solution would be in jQuery. I know that's tending toward opinion (again), but if possible jQuery really would be a better means to address the OP.

Comment: @BobC: I would disagree if this (or this and a few other things) is the only thing OP needs to do. It doesn't make sense to load an entire library if you're not going to use 99% of it.

Comment: True. As he used the expression toggle I assumed it was allusive to the jQuery function.

Answer (score 0):

```
td = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
    for (var  i = 0; i < td.length; i++) {
        if (td[i].className === 'foo')
            if (!td[i].style.display)
                td[i].style.display = 'none';
            else    
                td[i].style.display = '';
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qwertymk/cyZn9/2/

Comment: This answer will not work if td has multiple classes, such as `<td class="foo bar">`.

Comment: I know but I was going for readability and cross-browser, not for advanced regex class detection

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it:

```
var trs = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
for (var i in trs) {
    var tr = trs[i];
    if (tr.getElementsByClassName("foo").length > 0)
        tr.style.display = (tr.style.display == "none" ? "block" : "none");
}
```

This will toggle the display on any TR that contains a child with class="foo".

Comment: IE doesn't support `getElementsByClassName` until IE 9.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` is [not supported through IE8](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#fivemethods).

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var toggle = function (action) {
        var trs = document.getElementById('bar').getElementsByTagName('tr'),
            trs_count = trs.length,
            needed = [],
            total = 0,
            pattern = /\bfoo\b/g,
            initial= 'show';

        for (i=0; i<trs_count; i++) {
            var tds = trs[i].getElementsByTagName('td'),
                tds_count = tds.length;

            for (j=0; j<tds_count; j++) {
                if (pattern.exec(tds[j].className)) {
                    needed.push(tds[j]);
                    total++;
                }
            }
        }

        toggle = function (action) {
            if (this.display == null) {
                this.display = initial;
            }

            if (action == null) {
                this.display = (this.display == 'hide') ? 'show' : 'hide';
            }
            else {
                this.display = action;
            }
            for (i=0; i<total; i++) {
                if (this.display == 'show') {
                    needed[i].style.display = 'block';
                }
                else {
                    needed[i].style.display = 'none';
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

        return toggle();
    }


    </script>
</head>
<body>

<table id="bar">
    <tr><th>Header</th></tr>
    <tr><td class="foo">1 Data foo</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2 Data</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="foo">3 Data foo</td></tr>
    <tr><td>4 Data</td></tr>
</table>

<button type="button" onclick="toggle()">toggle</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Another user tried your code and found a problem: it won't match every other cell, as the regex internal pointer is moved forward on each `exec` call. You could just remove the "g" flag from the regex to fix it. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/16578232/825789.