# Toggle(show/hide) the selected odd and even columns of a table

Tags: javascript

I have tried the following code, but it is not working for even columns as can be seen from the given example. I couldnot identify the problem. Please help me with necessary corrections. I am only an enthusiastic learner.

CSS:

```
.foo{visibility:hidden};
.faa{visibility:hidden};
.fii{visibility:hidden};
```

JavaScript :

```
var toggle = function (action) {
    var trs = document.getElementById('bar').getElementsByTagName('tr'),
        trs_count = trs.length,
        needed = [],
        total = 0,
        pattern = /faa|foo|fii\b/g,
        initial= 'show';

    for (i=0; i<trs_count; i++) {
        var tds = trs[i].getElementsByTagName('td'),
            tds_count = tds.length;
        for (j=0; j<tds_count; j++) {
            if (pattern.exec(tds[j].className)) {
                needed.push(tds[j]);
                total++;
            }
        }
    }

    toggle = function (action) {
        if (this.display == null) {
            this.display = initial;
        }
        if (action == null) {
            this.display = (this.display == 'hide') ? 'show' : 'hide';
        }
        else {
            this.display = action;
        }
        for (i=0; i<total; i++) {
            if (this.display == 'show') {
                needed[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';//changed from display = 'block';
            }
            else {
                needed[i].style.visibility = 'visible';//changed from display = 'none';
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    return toggle();
}
```

HTML:

```
<DIV ALIGN="center" style="display:none">
<!-- used the following patterns. but of no use
/f(\w)\1/g, //f(\w)\1/g,  /\bfoo\b/g, /faa|foo|fii\b/g, -->
</DIV>

<TABLE id="bar" class="reg" ALIGN="CENTER" BORDER=1 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0 WIDTH="90%">
    <TR ALIGN="left" VALIGN="middle">
        <TD width="20%"> URL of Site</TD>
        <TD width="20%">User I
        <span onclick="toggle()">D</span> // the event handler
        /Nickname</TD>
        <TD ALIGN="left" width="10%" align="center" nowrap>xxx</TD>
        <TD width="30%">Clue</TD>
        <TD width="20%">Other Information</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR ALIGN="left" VALIGN="middle">
        <TD>xxxxxxxxxxxxx</TD>
        <TD>xxxxxxxxxxxxx</TD>
        <td class="foo">xxxxxxxxx</td>
        <TD class="faa">xxxxxxxxx</TD>
        <TD class="fii">xxxxxxxxxx</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR ALIGN="left" VALIGN="middle">
        <TD>xxxxxxxxxxxxx</TD>
        <TD>xxxxxxxxxxxxx</TD>
        <td class="foo">xxxxxxxxx</td>
        <TD class="faa">xxxxxxxxx</TD>
        <TD class="fii">xxxxxxxxxx</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR ALIGN="left" VALIGN="middle">
        <TD>xxxxxxxxxxxxx</TD>
        <TD>xxxxxxxxxxxxx</TD>
        <td class="foo">xxxxxxxxx</td>
        <TD class="faa">xxxxxxxxx</TD>
        <TD class="fii">xxxxxxxxxx</TD>
    </TR>
</TABLE>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6yGeN/1/)

Comment: Try:

`.foo, .faa, .fii {display:none;}`

That may get you closer...

Comment: what do you actually wants to happen

Comment: Suggest to `var toggle=...` instead of `toggle=...` in your closure.

Comment: Nothing works. If I use display attribute foo and faa works, and if it is visibility foo and fii are togled. Mr.Xavier Barbosa Who posted the above script in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594631/toggle-table-row-visibility-based-on-presence-of-td-class, may be able to tell.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
.foo, .faa, .fii {visibility:hidden}
```

This is Jsfiddle [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6yGeN/23/)

Comment: does not work. JSFiddle never shows up anything for me, I don't know why.

Comment: it works fine for me. You only change the CSS like above . try this:http://jsbin.com/ojoriy/1/edit

Comment: Changing CSS makes no difference. Columns 3and 5 are getting toggled but not 4.
I don't know how it works for Laughing. In jsbin also, only 3and 5 columns are getting toggled. My querry is to toggle 3,4,and 5 columns i.e., odd and even columns simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Every time `exec` (or `test`, which you might want to use instead) finds a match, it advances a `lastIndex` property on the regular expression object, and the next match attempt will start at that position on the string. So when you match "foo", the next search will start at index 3 of "faa" (so you'll be matching against an empty string).

That only happens when your regular expression object uses the global flag "g", so the simplest solution here is to simply remove that flag (since you're not looking for multiple matches within the same class name):

```
// ...
pattern = /(faa|foo|fii)\b/,
// ...
```

Also, you should fix your CSS rules as Laughing already pointed out. The semicolons should be inside the curly braces:

```
.foo{visibility:hidden;}
.faa{visibility:hidden;}
.fii{visibility:hidden;}
```

Comment: Also, that seems like a cumbersome piece of code for such a simple task. I would look for a simpler solution (which would start by not using inline event handlers like `onclick="funcName()"`).

Comment: Thanks Mr.bfavaretto, After removing the global flag both the odd and even columns are toggled. As commented will you provide a cute javascript code.